# C++ finding highest value

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I can't seem to figure out how to my code to return and print the student(s) with the highest grade. I've been very sick this semester(mono), so I've missed quite a few lectures. I was wondering if anybody could help me print the student with the highest grade's name, grade and average.
Thank you!

Hi, I can't seem to get my code to print out the Student with the highest average. It prints out a bunch of numbers and the average and the lettergrade are not correct. If somebody could explain to me what is going on it would be wonderful!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string fName;
    string lName;
    int score1;
    int score2;
    int score3;
    int score4;
    int score5;
    char letterGrade;
    int averageTest;
};

void avgAndassignGrade(Student array[], int size);
void sortAlpha(Student array[], int size);
void PrintStudents(Student arr[], int size);
int findHighest(Student arr[], int size);
void PrintStudentsHighest(Student arr[], int grade, int size);

int main()
{
    int counter=0;
    Student class120[50];

    ifstream file( "grades.txt" );
    string line;

    if ( !file )
        cout<<"No file found.";
    if ( file.is_open() )
    {
        while ( getline (file,line) )
        {
            file >> class120[counter].fName
                 >> class120[counter].lName 
                 >> class120[counter].score1
                 >> class120[counter].score2
                 >> class120[counter].score3
                 >> class120[counter].score4
                 >> class120[counter].score5;
            counter++;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    avgAndassignGrade( class120, counter );
    sortAlpha( class120, counter );
    int grade = findHighest( class120, counter );
    PrintStudents( class120, counter );
    PrintStudentsHighest( class120, grade, counter );
}

void avgAndassignGrade(Student array[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        int total = array[i].score1 + array[i].score2 + array[i].score3 + array[i].score4
                    + array[i].score5;
        array[i].averageTest = total / 5;
        if ( array[i].averageTest > 89 && array[i].averageTest < 100 )
            array[i].letterGrade = 'A';
        if ( array[i].averageTest > 79 && array[i].averageTest < 90 )
            array[i].letterGrade= 'B';
        if ( array[i].averageTest > 69 && array[i].averageTest < 80 )
            array[i].letterGrade= 'C';
        if ( array[i].averageTest > 59 && array[i].averageTest < 70 )
            array[i].letterGrade = 'D';
        if ( array[i].averageTest < 60 )
            array[i].letterGrade = 'E';
    }
}

void sortAlpha(Student array[],int size)
{
    Student temp;
    for ( int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < size - 1; l++)
        {
            if ( array[l].lName > array[l+1].lName )
            {
                temp = array[l];
                array[l] = array[l+1];
                array[l+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int findHighest(Student arr[], int size)
{
    int large = arr[0].averageTest;
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        if ( large < arr[i].averageTest ) {
            large = arr[i].averageTest;
        }
    }
    return large;
}

void PrintStudents(Student arr[], int size) {
    cout << "Name" << "\t\t" << "Average" << "\t\t" << "Grade" << "\n";
    for ( int i = 1; i < size; i++ )
    {
        cout << arr[i].lName + "," + arr[i].fName << "\t\t" << arr[i].averageTest << "\t\t" 
             << arr[i].letterGrade <<"\n";
    }
}

void PrintStudentsHighest( Student arr[], int grade, int size ) {
    Student high;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        if( arr[i].averageTest == grade)
            high=arr[i];
    }
    cout << "The student(s) with the highest grade."<< '\n'
         << "Name"<<"\t\t"<<"Average"<<"\t\t"<<"Grade"<<"\n"
         << high.lName + "," + high.fName << "\t\t" << high.averageTest << "\t\t"
         << high.letterGrade << endl;
}
```

---

edit: I changed the code. Now it prints out something for the highest grade, but it is just a jumbled mess of numbers. I am trying to find the Student with the HighestAverage and print his/her name average and letter grade.

Comment: Have you considered talking to your professor? It is their job to help you learn. If you missed some classes due to illness most professors will be happy to spend some extra time with you to help you learn the material that you missed.

Comment: You could also compare your program with programs submitted by other people.  Search StackOverflow for "c++ grade array"

Comment: There are many duplicates, try this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+grade&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb

Comment: You also have to tell us what exactly is wrong when you run this code? Does it prints something? Is the printed result wrong? Unsorted, with errors in values?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you are trying to do... But if you are trying to find the highest value between many numbers you have to do something like this:

```
int max = 0;
if (grade > max)
   max = grade;
```

and you can create array to replace score1, score2.... so it's like that:

```
int scores[5]; //it's so easier to deal with :)
```

then adding scores will be with for loop (5 loops)!!!

For more help... you can explain more about your program to help you more!!! 
i hope it's helpful for you!!

Comment: Hi Mohammad! I am comparing the students' averages to see who has the highest.

Comment: I get this... It's so simple... By our life if we wanna get the highest value of many values we look one by one to know the highest one... And in programming it's the same .. So if we encounter any highest value we save it.. so we gonna have finally the highest one between the values that we deal with... So simply loop on all values like you've done in findHighest function and if you encounter value bigger than the large value save it.. so when you end the loop you gonna get the highest one!!!

Comment: Thank you for your help Mohammad! I figured it out!